# Mechanize question regarding submit()

Tags: perl, mechanize, bioinformatics

I tried looking around on the forum and googling for answers but cannot figure it out. After submitting a form for a webpage that requires time to do some computation does Mechanize wait for all the computation to finish (even if it's taking an hour?). It seems as if that doesn't happen. I am iterating through a subroutine that creates a Mechanize object and submits a form and downloads the output file after computation is done. However, I feel like it jumps to the next iteration of loop without completing all those tasks since some times the computation takes a long time. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks. This is the subroutine

```
sub microinspector {
        my ($sequence, $folder) = @_;
        print STDOUT "subroutine sequence: $sequence\n";
        my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new();
        $browser->get("http://bioinfo.uni-plovdiv.bg/microinspector/");
        $browser->form_number(1);
        $browser->field("target_sequence", $sequence);
        $browser->select("Choose an organism : ", "Mus musculus");

        $browser->submit();
        #print $browser->content();
        my @links = $browser->links();

        chdir($folder) or die "Cannot chdir to $folder";

        foreach my $link (@links) {
                #print $link->url();
                if( $link->url() =~ /csv$/i ){
                        my $result = $browser->get( $link->url() );
                        my $filename = ( $link->url() =~ /\/([^\/]+)$/ )[0];
                        print "Saving $filename\n";
                        open( OUT, ">$filename" );
                        print OUT $result->content();
                        close( OUT );
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WWW::Mechanize` can take an optional `timeout` parameter (specified in seconds) in its constructor (which is passed to its parent class `LWP::UserAgent` in this case).  I think the default is like 180 seconds.

Try increasing it, like:

```
my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    timeout => 60 * 10,     # 10 minutes
);
```

See the `LWP::UserAgent` docs on the `timeout` method for the specific semantics of how this is treated.  It's mostly as you expect, but just in case.